# Unable to add an icon to my progam build by py2exe

Tags: python-3.x, windows, pygame, icons, py2exe

I've got a small program named "taquin" and I want to add an icon to the executable file.

- My icon file is a image file 32x32 pixels extracted from a windows dll.
- This program is built by py2exe with this small code

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

setup(
    options = {'py2exe': {'bundle_files': 1, 'compressed': True}},
    windows = [
        {
            "script" : 'taquin.py',
            "icon_ressources" : [(1, "taquin.ico")],
        }
    ],
)
```

Could you help me please ? My operating system is Windows 10...

All the code is here : [draft.ericberthomier.fr/taquin.zip](https://draft.ericberthomier.fr/taquin.zip)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a program called `auto-py-to-exe` which creates an exe out of your program without requiring you to create a setup file. The interface is great and allows you to easily create and exe without creating a setup.py. This also allows you to package your app as a single exe, without any other files. Below is a screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

You can install the program by typing into the command line:

`python -m pip install auto-py-to-exe`

You can run it by typing in:

`auto-py-to-exe`

To see more about auto-py-to-exe, please visit the PyPI page at https://pypi.org/project/auto-py-to-exe/.

Comment: Works fine. Thanks

Comment: Great! Good for you!